# browser().navigateTo hangs if $state.transitionTo is called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-e2e

If I call $state.transitionTo() inside the setup for a controller, e.g. to canonicalize the URL, this causes browser().navigateTo() to hang permanently if the action changes the local state of an URL.

That is, let's say I have an URL schema with valid states such as this:
  /graphs/:graph_id
  /graphs/:graph_id/help

And I'm navigating to, say, /graphs/17.

If the controller changes that to /graphs/42, angular-scenario hangs. (Or, specifically, karma-ng-scenario hangs, in case that matters.)

If it changes it to /graphs/17/help, the test runs successfully (/help just adding an overlay).

Am I doing URL canonicalization wrong, is this a genuine bug in angular-scenario, or what?